# Malicious File Upload

Tags: plugins, security

Our company has a wordpress website. I am using Wordfence for security. Today Wordfence blocked and identified an attack. This is the message I got: **Blocked for Malicious File Upload (PHP)**.

The site does not have any way to upload files (as far as I know). Only admins can upload files from the backend. I want to find the method that the file was uploaded. How do I find this vulnerability?